# How to open Html view in new page from mvc controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to open html view page in new window from controller . This view also has  input dynamic object.
I tried to use Redirect/RedirectToAction/redirectPremanent/RedirectToActionPermanent but none of this works it shows the path in browser url section but shows the blank page.
Is there any otherway to achieve it.i can not use jquery like window.open or html tag.

Comment: Do you Want to open the View in a New browser window..??

Comment: Can you share some code with expected sample behavior and what unexpected things you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by creating one intermediate view which will redirect it to new window but now it create new issue,popup blocker blocks new opened window

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type type, string key, string script, bool addScriptTags);
```

I m not sure that is really possible in other way.